# Determine number of leading zeros in a floating point number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, floating-point, language-agnostic

How can I calculate how many zeros come after the decimal point but before the first non-zero in a floating point number. Examples:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
1.0 -> 0
1.1 -> 0
1.01 -> 1
1.00003456 ->4
```

Intuitively I assume there is a math function that provides this, or at least does the main part. But I can neither recall nor figure out which one.

I know it can be done by first converting the number to a string, as long as the number isn't in scientific notation, but I want a pure math solution.

In my case I don't need something that works for negative numbers if that's a complication.

I'd like to know what the general ways to do it are, irrespective of language.

But if there is a pretty standard math function for this, I would also like to know if JavaScript has this function.

As a sidenote, I wonder if this calculation is related to the method for determining how many digits are required for the decimal representation of an integer.

Comment: I have updated my answer, just realized made a small mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let `x` be a non-whole number that can be written as `n` digits of the whole part, then the decimal point, then `m` zeroes, then the rest of the fractional part.

> x = [a<sub>1</sub>a<sub>2</sub>...a<sub>n</sub>] **.** [0<sub>1</sub>0<sub>2</sub>...0<sub>m</sub>][b<sub>1</sub>b<sub>2</sub>...b<sub>m</sub>]

This means that the fractional part of `x` is larger than or equal to 10<sup>–m</sup>, and smaller than 10<sup>–m+1</sup>.

In other words, the decimal logarithm of the fractional part of `x` is larger than or equal to `–m`, and smaller than `–m+1`.

Which, in turn, means that the whole part of the decimal logarithm of the fractional part of `x` equals `–m`.

```js
function numZeroesAfterPoint(x) {
  if (x % 1 == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    return -1 - Math.floor(Math.log10(x % 1));
  }
}

console.log(numZeroesAfterPoint(0));
console.log(numZeroesAfterPoint(1));
console.log(numZeroesAfterPoint(1.0));
console.log(numZeroesAfterPoint(1.1));
console.log(numZeroesAfterPoint(1.01));
console.log(numZeroesAfterPoint(1.00003456));
```

> As a sidenote, I wonder if this calculation is related to the method for determining how many digits are required for the decimal representation of an integer.

In the same manner, a positive integer `x` takes `n` decimal digits to represent it if and only if `n - 1 <= log10(x) < n`.

So the number of digits in the decimal representation of `x` is `floor(log10(x)) + 1`.

That said, I wouldn't recommend using this method of determining the number of digits in practice. `log10` is not guaranteed to give the exact value of the logarithm (not even as exact as IEEE 754 permits), which may lead to incorrect results in some edge cases.

Comment: In my case I'm only dealing with currencies and exchange rates. I was using 4 decimal places but that broke down when I compared IRR to KWD so I got interested in it as a pure math problem too (-:

Comment: To add to this excellent answer: calculations based on decimal representations of floating point numbers are always going to be problematic due to the inherent inexactness compared with the underlying binary format. Before trying to do this, I would recommend trying to understand how floating point numbers work: one good place to start is www.exploringbinary.com.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because I was able to independently come up with a while loop solution but I was really interested in a mathematical solution.

Comment: Due to aforementioned floating point problems, it returns 3 for `1.001`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple `while` loop:

```
function CountZeros(Num) {

    var Dec = Num % 1;
    var Counter = -1;

    while ((Dec < 1) && (Dec > 0)) {
        Dec = Dec * 10;
        Counter++;
    }
    Counter = Math.max(0, Counter); // In case there were no numbers at all after the decimal point.

    console.log("There is: " + Counter + " zeros");
}
```

Then just pass the number you want to check into the function:

```
CountZeros(1.0034);
```

Comment: this doesn't work stable, when `1.0000340001120` entered it returns 4

Comment: still returns 4

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: when that number is entered, it should return 7, when this number is entered `1.00003400011200000` it should still return 7

Comment: @turmuka please read the original questions ___how many zeros come AFTER the decimal point BUT BEFORE the first non-zero___

Comment: @turmuka reading fast aside, what would be the purpose of counting ALL zeros after the decimal point?

Comment: not counting all, counting ALL until the LAST non-zero number @MattNewelski

Comment: I've also updated my answer as soon as I've realized the real question @MattNewelski :)

Answer (score 2):

My approach is using a `while()` loop that compares the `.floor(n)` value with the `n.toFixed(x)` value of it while incrementing `x` until the two are not equal:

```js
console.log(getZeros(0));           //0
console.log(getZeros(1));           //0
console.log(getZeros(1.0));         //0
console.log(getZeros(1.1));         //0
console.log(getZeros(1.01));        //1
console.log(getZeros(1.00003456));  //4

function getZeros(num) {
    var x = 0;
    if(num % 1 === 0) return x;
    while(Math.floor(num)==num.toFixed(x)) {x++;}
    return(x-1);
}
```

Comment: While using loops might seem inefficient, it works correctly for `1.001` value, unlike the accepted answer which returns 3 for `1.001`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `toFixed()` method, but there is only one flaw in my code, you need to specify the length of the numbers that comes after the point `.` It is because of the way the method is used.

**NOTE:**

The max length for `toFixed()` method is 20, so don't enter more than 20 numbers after `.` as said   [in the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

```
var num = 12.0003400;

var lengthAfterThePoint = 7;
var l = num.toFixed(lengthAfterThePoint);
var pointFound = false;
var totalZeros = 0;

for(var i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
  if(pointFound == false){
    if(l[i] == '.'){
      pointFound = true;
    }
  }else{
    if(l[i] != 0){
      break;
    }else{
      totalZeros++;
    }
  }
}
console.log(totalZeros);
```

**Extra Answer**

This is my extra answer, in this function, the program counts all the zeros until the last *non-zero*. So it ignores all the zeros at the end.

```
var num = 12.034000005608000;

var lengthAfterThePoint = 15;
var l = num.toFixed(lengthAfterThePoint);
var pointFound = false;
var theArr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < l.length; i++){
  if(pointFound == false){
    if(l[i] == '.'){
      pointFound = true;
    }
  }else{
    theArr.push(l[i]);
  }
}


var firstNumFound = false;
var totalZeros = 0;

for(var j = 0; j < theArr.length; j++){
  if(firstNumFound == false){
    if(theArr[j] != 0){
      firstNumFound = true;
      totalZeros = totalZeros + j;
    }
  }else{
    if(theArr[j] == 0){
      totalZeros++;
    }
  }
}


var totalZerosLeft = 0;
for (var k = theArr.length; k > 0; k--) {
  if(theArr[k -1] == 0){
    totalZerosLeft++;
  }else{
    break;
  }
}

console.log(totalZeros - totalZerosLeft);
```